# Use sed to find and replace a number following by its successor in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, operators

I have a string that contains multiple occurrences of number ranges, which are separated by a comma, e.g.,

2-12,59-89,90-102,103-492,593-3990,3991-4930

Now I would like to remove all directly neighbouring ranges and remove them from the string, i.e., remove anything that is of the form `-(x),(x+1)`, to get something like this:

2-12,59-492,593-4930

Can anyone think of a method to accomplish this? I can honestly not post anything that I have tried, because all my tries were highly unsuccessful. To me it seems like it is not possible to actually find anything of the form `-(x),(x+1)` using sed, since that would require doing operations or comparisons of a found number by another number that has to be part of the command that is currently searching for numbers.

If everybody agrees that sed is NOT the correct tool for doing this, I will do it another way, but I am still interested if it's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `awk`

```
awk -F, -v RS="-" -v ORS="-" '$2!=$1+1' file
```

with appropriate separator setting, print the record when second field is not +1.

`RS` is the record separator and `ORS` is the outpout record separator.

test:

```
> awk -F, -v RS="-" -v ORS="-"
 '$2!=$1+1' <<< "2-12,59-89,90-102,103-492,593-3990,3991-4930"

2-12,59-492,593-4930
```

Comment: this is the `awk` way!

Comment: Now that is working! Since I didn't really know awk, I would not have thought of using it, but obviously it is the proper way...

Answer (score 2):

**awk** solution:

```
awk -F'-' '{   r=$1; 
               for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) { 
                   split($i, a, ","); 
                   r=sprintf("%s%s", r, a[2]-a[1]==1? "" : FS $i) 
               } 
               print r 
           }' file
```

---

- `-F'-'` - treat `-`(hyphen) as field separator
- `r` - resulting string
- `split($i, a, ",")` - split adjacent *range* boundaries into array `a` by separator `,`
- `a[2]-a[1]==1` - crucial condition, reflects `(x),(x+1)`

---

The output:

```
2-12,59-492,593-4930
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works as expected! But since thanasisp's anwer is simpler and works, I have marked it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ' s/^/\n/;:a;ta;s/\n([^-]*-)([0-9]*)(.*,)/\1\n\2\n\2\n\3/;Td;:b;s/(\n.*\n.*)9(_*\n)/\1_\2/;tb;s/(\n.*\n)(_*\n)/\10\2/;s/$/\n0123456789/;s/(\n.*\n[0-9]*)([0-8])(_*\n.*)\n.*\2(.).*/\1\4\3/;:z;tz;s/(\n.*\n[^_]*)_([^\n]*\n)/\10\2/;tz;:c;tc;s/([0-9]*-)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n,(\3)-/\n\1/;ta;s/\n(.*)\n.*\n,/\1,\n/;ta;:d;s/\n//g' file
```

This proof-of-concept sed solution, iteratively increments and compares the end of one range with the start of another. If the comparison is true it removes both and repeats, otherwise it moves on to the next range and repeats until all ranges have been compared.

Comment: First of all...holy crap. Good effort for finding a possibility! Unfortunately, the string that I have is in reality a bit more complex and contains a few underscores in the beginning which are changed to a ``0`` for some reason. Otherwise it works!

Comment: @phil13131 Sorry I was a little too free with my `_`'s and used `y/_/0/` to replace them thus replacing all `_`'s in the pattern space. Should be more specific now.